# Sum: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-an^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an analytical expression for this sum, perhaps in terms of special functions:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-an^2)$$

where $a$ is a positive real constant.

Comment: [Jacobi theta functions.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the hint of Simply ...

One of the Jacobi theta functions is
$$
\vartheta_3(z,q) := 1+2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2}\cos(2 n z)
$$
and thus
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-an^2) = \frac{\vartheta_3(0,e^{-a})+1}{2}
$$
and
$$
\vartheta_3(0,e^{-a}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \exp(-an^2)
$$